# Cancel inline row editing manually?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When the user clicks add and hits the reload button without saving the row, the Add button is not restored. The Save & Cancel buttons are still active. How do I cancel inline row editing manually? Or is there a way to find these buttons so I can hide them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the button added by [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#inlinenav) you need to remove the class `'ui-state-disabled'` (call `.removeClass('ui-state-disabled')`). To disable the button you need to add the class `'ui-state-disabled'` (call `.addClass('ui-state-disabled')`). To identify (to select with respect of jQuery) the buttons you need to know that the id of the buttons will be constructed from the grid's id and the suffix constructed based on the button name: `"_ilsave"`, `"_ilcancel"`, `"_iladd"`, `"_iledit"`. For example if the id of the grid is `"list"` then the id of the save button will be `"list_ilsave"`.

To reset the state the buttons before or after refreshing the grid you can use `afterRefresh` or `beforeRefresh` callbacks of `navGrid` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#parameters)) or to do this inside of `loadComplete` callback. For example

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var idSelector = "#" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id);
    $(idSelector +"_ilsave").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    $(idSelector +"_ilcancel").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    $(idSelector +"_iladd").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
    $(idSelector +"_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
}
```

Alternatively you can use `showAddEditButtons` instead of all the above calls:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid("showAddEditButtons");
}
```

I included the above code mostly for the case that you need to do other kind of "enabling" or "disabling" of the buttons.

Comment: Oleg - is the master of jqGrid

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you very much, Oleg. I was able to find the buttons by their id's and and enabled/disabled them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `restoreRow` function, see here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing&s%5B%5D=editrow

You could make a button that would always restore the selected row with a function like this:

```
$('#the_button').click(function(){
    var rowid = jQuery('#grid_id').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('restoreRow',rowid, function(){});
});
```

Comment: I don't want to restore the row. I want to trigger the cancel event. I tried your code anyway and didn't work. The grid is initially empty. The rowid retrieved is 'new_row'. Any ideas?

Comment: can you supply your grid definition? I still think you need to use the restoreRow function.  I assume you are using the inline Nav buttons.

Comment: This is my first time with jqgrid. Here's the code - http://pastebin.com/FFgb3dTY Is that what you are looking for?